# Share website blogpost on google plus

Tags: share, social-networking

I have my website in which there is a blog section with various posts.when user click on any post it navigates to post detail page. i have a google plus share button on that page. gshare button is working however the problem is that it does not show the correct image and also now showing the title of the post when click on it for sharing.following code i am using for generating the button.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Share demo: Basic page</title>
        <link rel="canonical" href="http://europa.promaticstechnologies.com/socialfit360/cmspages/blog2/IixTQGAKYAo=" />
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer>
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <g:plus action="share"></g:plus>
    </body>
</html>
```

The href in the head tag is the link of my webpage. i am using cakephp framework so i placed the meta tags in my layout file inside head tags.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $blog['ManageBlog']['title']; ?>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php  echo HTTP_ROOT.'img/club_home/'.$blog['ManageBlog']['picture']?>" />
```

After doing all this when I click on share button it gives title is default title of my website not my blogpost title, description is correct but image is also not correct, it fetch total 3 images may post's image is in third place. there is to next and previous button on the image when we select the correct image description is gone. i don't know what is happening. I tried all the things specified in this [**link**](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/?hl=en). I also tried **Schema.org microdata** and Open Graph protocol.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why google+ shows wrong image of my post is due to image dimensions. your post image at least of 300px in height and 300px in width. In my case why google is fetching the wrong images because wrong images has distentions greater than of my post thumbnail image.as i upload the greater dimension image it fetchs the correct image.